# Login to another tty

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, terminal, raspbian

I have RPi3 with Raspbian Stretch in it. When I boot it up, It says

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux raspberrypi tty1

raspberrypi login:
```

Then I ssh into it and in ssh session, I type

```
echo -e "pi\n" >> /dev/tty1
```

I see my input `pi` immediately on the other login screen. 
But couldn't find a way to transfer  input. 
Tried these lines with no luck:

- `echo -e "\n"`
- `echo -e "\r"`
- `echo ""`
- `printf "\n"`
- `printf "\r"`

Couldn't get to the password section. They're just printing new lines into username input.

I also tried `screen /dev/tty1`. After hitting `Enter`, screen is cleared and when I type something, it appears on the other login screen but hitting `Enter` just moves the carriage to the beginning of the line.

I started to think that it is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [write commands from one terminal to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376251/linux-write-commands-from-one-terminal-to-another) (See the answer that uses TIOCSTI)

Answer (score 0):

You can do, but you have to redirect input (there are some drawbacks however), if you try

```
read LINE <</dev/tty1
echo $LINE
```

you can observe that what you have input on `/dev/tty1` is being echoed in your ssh session (well, not exactly)

What happens is that when you do execute the `read` command (it's an internal `bash(1)` command) the kernel will give the input of the terminal to one of the processes that are waiting for it (either the shell you are running, or the `read`  command you issued from the other session) and the result will be nasty (part of the input goes to one process and part to the other)

Comment: This is the opposite of my goal actually. Physical login is on `/dev/tty1`.
To get an input from this code, the code should be running at `/dev/tty1` which is not possible because I am not logged in. I want to send my inputs **from the ssh session** to a **not logged in tty**.

Comment: if you want to **write** on a tty, redirect output of your command to it, as in `echo Something >/dev/tty1`.  But you asked about your input, not your output.